# ScheduleExpression and increments

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I was experimenting with `ScheduleExpression` and noticed a strange behavior:

If I create a timer every 30 seconds with

```
scheduleExpression.second("*/30");
```

I get

```
[second=*/30;minute=*;hour=*;dayOfMonth=*;month=*;dayOfWeek=*;year=*;timezoneID=null;start=null;end=null]
```

and my timer is executed every 30 seconds (at :00 and :30) as expected. So far so good.

I then tried to do the same with minutes

```
scheduleExpression.minute("*/1");
```

and as expected I get

```
[second=*;minute=*/1;hour=*;dayOfMonth=*;month=*;dayOfWeek=*;year=*;timezoneID=null;start=null;end=null]
```

but my `@Timeout` method is called continuously. The code is exactly the same I am just changing the `ScheduleExpression`.

Is this a know issue? Or did I misinterpret the documentation and I have to set both

```
scheduleExpression.second(0);
scheduleExpression.minute("*/1");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `ScheduleExpression` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression.html) it seems that you should call both methods (especially if you scheduled `seconds` before).

Look at this:

```
Example : ( minute = "∗/14", hour="1,2")
```

They are setting both `minutes` and `hours`.

Comment: But in this case also the seconds should be set otherwise it will be executed at 14:00, 14:01, ...

Comment: I think seconds by default set to `0`.

Comment: seems so from the documentation but not in my case: I had to explicitly set it to '0'